# how to add nodes to existing Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

I am using aws C++ sdk.
I have successfully created Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue object from a string (parsing was OK).
How can I navigate to a particular **sub-node** and add some additional fields and values (it has complex structure, it's a event json of a kinesis data stream lambda call). I need to populate this event with certain additional data so that I then send this json to another lamba call.

there is a class called JsonView which allows me to navigate to particular nodes of my tree-like JSON event. But documentation mentiones that JsonView is a **read-only** representation. However I need to be able *to add* more nodes and values to a certain *sub-node* of my JSON - that is - I need to first get an item from array, then I need to get to a certain field, which is a structure by itself and then only I need to add members to that nested field) ... not sure how do I do it.. thanks in advance for help!